# How to delete security software without a password?

Tags: filesystems, delete-file, data-recovery

I have a security software installed on my computer called greenguard from the company greenware and every time I turn the computer off and on it deletes all the things that have been downloaded or done to the computer and resets it to the way it was when it was set up and I try to delete it and needs a password

I tried to delete it like you normally delete it and a window appears asking for a username and password and I also tried to delete all of its files and it deleted some because it was running in the background and when I closed it it opened again and then I was able to delete most of it and it restored everything and I tried to delete through a system administrator in the application remover